# AutoLayout: Child View goes Over Parent View's Bounds

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I'm new to iOS development. I have a `contentView` for a `UICollectionViewCell` and I want to add another view to it. I want this new view to be stretched to the `contentView` edges. I'm trying to achieve this using AutoLayout, so here is what I did:

```
let view = UIView();
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
contentView.addSubview(view)

view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

This worked as expected and I got the behavior that I want. Then I wanted the `contentView` to have a padding of 18 points, so I figured that I need to add the constant parameter and set it to 18 like this:

```
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
```

What I was expecting is that the new view now would have a smaller area than before, since it is now pushed from all directions by 18 points. What I did get though is a view with the same size as in the first scenario that is pushed by 18 points from the top and the left and goes over the bounds of the `contentView`!

Can you please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: try -18 instead for top and left

Comment: If you're open to not using AutoLayout, you can do this easily with a single line: `view.frame = contentView.bounds.insetBy(dx: 18, dy: 18)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constants are all pointing in the same direction, so the view is just offset.

This should work:

```
view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 18).isActive = true
view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -18).isActive = true
```